# Existing 3 wire subpanel installed 30 years ago, swimming pool lights and outlets working, do i need to add a neutral or ground wire?

Tags: subpanel

I have a Eaton Challenger subpanel in garage that powers pool lights and outlets through 2 20-amp single pole gfci. Fed by a 90 amp double 2-wire breaker at main panel, 60 feet away. Only 1 smaller ground wire, 6awg, also serves as neutral in bonded box. Worked for 30 years, but adding an led pool light. Should i leave   circuit breaker panel alone or try to install a fourth wire, regardless of cost? (No record or evidence of any body being shocked).

Comment: You cannot use the ground wire as a neutral. AIUI, that was illegal even 30 years ago.

Comment: Picture of the panel?

Comment: Also, using an undersized wire as neutral is dangerous and could burn up under a heavy unbalanced load.

Comment: Is this garage attached to the house, or a separate structure?  Also, just how much load is this subpanel powering anyway?

Comment: I lost my post. Thanks for all the help. I decided im gonna cut holes in plastet ceiling and pull a new 2awg wire through then probably get a larger subpanel. Eventually i plan to extend the attached garage 24 more feet. This will give the pwer i need to supply that and the 15-20 amps i use for the pool. Outlets and lights. Thanks again.